# Unit Testing on a Xmpp Android app on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-studio, xmpp

I'm trying to code some unit test for some OnCreate() methode on my XMPP app on android Studio, the problem is that i have never done that and i'm a little bit lost.

Here is my methode :

```
public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG ="ChatActivity";

    private String contactJid;
    private ChatView mChatView;
    private SendButton mSendButton;
    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        mChatView =(ChatView) findViewById(R.id.rooster_chat_view);
        mChatView.setEventListener(new ChatViewEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void userIsTyping() {
                //Here you know that the user is typing
            }

            @Override
            public void userHasStoppedTyping() {
                //Here you know that the user has stopped typing.
            }
        });

        mSendButton = mChatView.getSendButton();
        mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Only send the message if the client is connected
                //to the server.

                if (RoosterConnectionService.getState().equals(RoosterConnection.ConnectionState.CONNECTED)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "The client is connected to the server,Sending Message");
                    //Send the message to the server

                    Intent intent = new Intent(RoosterConnectionService.SEND_MESSAGE);
                    intent.putExtra(RoosterConnectionService.BUNDLE_MESSAGE_BODY,
                            mChatView.getTypedString());
                    intent.putExtra(RoosterConnectionService.BUNDLE_TO, contactJid);

                    sendBroadcast(intent);

                    //Update the chat view.
                    mChatView.sendMessage();
                } else if (RoosterConnectionService.getState().equals(RoosterConnection.ConnectionState.DISCONNECTED)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Client not connected to server ,Message not sent!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        contactJid = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_CONTACT_JID");
        setTitle(contactJid);
    }
```

My question is that i don't know how to proceed and what to put in my OnCreateTest() method and what to test, could anyone help please :(

Comment: Your question as it is now is quite broad. It is not clear if you expect somebody to explain you how to do a unit test in general (which would be definitively too broad), how to deal with your code, or both... It would be better if you narrow down your question, my guess is you already know what a unit test is, since you want to do it, even if you've never done it. What exactly is your doubt when trying to write the test? Thanks.

Comment: My problem is that i don't know how to proceed, i already created the OnCreateTest() method, by i don't really know what to put inside and what to test. Sorry if my question is not clear,it's my first time postng  on Stackoverflow.